# Value from InputBox not added to the correct cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add the value input from my InputBox into a specific Column in a separate worksheet. The data does get added to the sheet but not in the first cell. It adds the data input in the cell A26 and I don't get why.

Here's the code: Where am I missing something?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim strDate$
Dim lngLstRow&, strLength&, lngSpaceLoc&
Dim sw1 As Boolean

  If MsgBox("Volume already planned?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
     "RIntegration") = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "OK, " & _
           "no further approval is needed", vbOKOnly, "Approval O.K"
  Else
    strTenderDate = InputBox("Enter the Date.", "Specify Date")

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
      lngLstRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row
      .Range("A" & lngLstRow).Value = strTenderDate
    End With

    MsgBox "Date successfully added to the database!", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Added!"
  End If
```

How can i specify that the cell A1 should be the starting point for the list?

Also is there a way to add a line of code in the beginning that automatically deletes the previous entries, without doing it by adding the delete code to an additional button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it should always use A1 then just write

```
.Range("A1").Value = strTenderDate
```

It looks like you still have data in the first 25 rows. can you try to delete those rows manually?

Comment: Well geez, that fixed it quickly. Now I feel stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're after this:

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    lngLstRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If .Cells(lngLstRow, 1) <> vbNullString Then lngLstRow = lngLstRow + 1
    .Cells(lngLstRow, 1).Value = strTenderDate
End With
```

Comment: @Thomas, did you try this solution?

Comment: @Thomas, it'd be nice of you to give feedback to people trying at helping you. thank you!

Comment: Oh I am very sorry for not answering. Yes this did also work for me, but I went for the other solution as it was a bit shorter.

Comment: I see. The real difference between the two solutions (and the reason why mine is a bit longer, too) is that mine always catches the first empty cell after last not empty one in column A. But if you don't need this feature and  _always_ want to write in cell A1, then mine is a little overkill.

Comment: I will use your code eventually, because this give me the option to create a history of data inputs. I'm pretty glad you posted this, because it seems to be super useful! Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. The "history" issue was quite obvious to me since your OP talked about _"starting point for the list"_.  You should accept the answer that you actually solves your question. Thank you